# ¿Como mantener desactivados los input text al reiniciar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, jsp, formularios

Buenas, tengo un problema, no hallo la manera en la cual al refrescar la pagina el input text queden deshabilitados,se habilitan y deshabilitan con un checkbox, el checkbox si me retorna desde la bd con el valor ya marcado, lo que deseo es que pueda verificar si el checkbox esta marcado entonces el input text se quede deshabilitado.

```js
String checkbox1          ="";

COMANDO=select v1 from bd;
rset = stmt.executeQuery(COMANDO);
      if(rset.next()){
checkbox1=rset.getString("v1");if(v1==null)v1="";
}
//Retornar valor desde la bd 
$("input[id=checkbox1[value='<%=checkbox1%>']").prop("checked",true);

 $('#checkbox1').click(function() {                               // Si esta seleccionado (si la propiedad checked es igual a true)
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {                                       $("#text").attr('disabled','disabled');                             } else {                                                             $("#text").removeAttr('disabled');
                                                              }
                                                          });
```

```html
 <tr>
<td colspan="3">Ubicación de placa cauterio:</td>
<td colspan="6"><input type="text"  size="20" id="text" name="text" value="<%=text%>" class="11" ></td>
<td ><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="3" class="checkiop" ></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así:

### Javascript puro

```js
window.onload = function() {
     var cbxCheck=document.getElementById('checkbox1');
     var bolChecked= cbxCheck.checked;
     var ibxText=document.getElementById('text');
     ibxText.disabled=bolChecked;
     cbxCheck.onchange = function() {
          bolChecked=this.checked;
          ibxText.disabled = bolChecked;
     };
};
```

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">Ubicación de placa cauterio:</td>
  <td colspan="6"><input type="text" size="20" id="text" name="text" value="<%=text%>" class="11" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="3" class="checkiop" checked /></td>
</tr>
```

---

Y lo contrario sería:

```js
window.onload = function() {
     var cbxCheck=document.getElementById('checkbox1');
     var bolChecked= cbxCheck.checked;
     var ibxText=document.getElementById('text');
     ibxText.disabled = !bolChecked;
     cbxCheck.onchange = function() {
          bolChecked=this.checked;
          ibxText.disabled = !bolChecked;
     };
};
```

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">Ubicación de placa cauterio:</td>
  <td colspan="6"><input type="text" size="20" id="text" name="text" value="<%=text%>" class="11" disabled /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="3" class="checkiop" /></td>
</tr>
```

---

### jQuery

```js
$(function() {

  var $cbxCheck = $('#checkbox1');
  var $bolChecked = $cbxCheck.is(':checked');
  var $ibxText = $('#text');
  $ibxText.prop('disabled', $bolChecked);

  $cbxCheck.change(function() {
      $bolChecked = this.checked;
      $ibxText.prop('disabled', $bolChecked);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">Ubicación de placa cauterio:</td>
  <td colspan="6"><input type="text" size="20" id="text" name="text" value="<%=text%>" class="11" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="3" class="checkiop" checked /></td>
</tr>
```